# XSL parent selector

Tags: xslt

XML

```
<dsInventory>
  <Room>
    <RoomName>kantoor 1</RoomName>
    <RoomId>1376257</RoomId>
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <RoomName>Hal</RoomName>
    <RoomId>1376258</RoomId>
  </Room>
<Method>
    <RoomId>1376257</RoomId>
    <Name>test</Name>
  </Method>
<Method>
    <RoomId>1376258</RoomId>
    <Name>test</Name>
  </Method>
</dsInventory>
```

XSL

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/dsInventory/Room">
        <xsl:for-each select="/dsInventory/Method">
             <xsl:if test="RoomId=../RoomId">
             </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Problem

I'm trying to select the methods for the corresponding rooms based on the roomid. however the selector ../RoomId doesn't work. How do i get the value of the RoomId from the first for-each? Or what is the proper way to select the methods for the rooms?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is context. The `if` condition is failing because it's running from the context of `Method` nodes, and therefore the XPath expression `../RoomID` is looking for a `RoomID` node on `dsInventory`. There is no such node.

You don't say what output you want, but based on the assumption that you simply want to iterate over rooms and find the method for each, try this: (note also I use templates rather than for-each loops, which are best avoided in XSL).

You can run it and see the output at **[this XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/5UZW2X)**.

```
<!-- kick things off from the point of dsInventory -->
<xsl:template match="dsInventory">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates select='Room' /></ul>
</xsl:template>

<!-- room nodes -->
<xsl:template match='Room'>
    <xsl:variable name='method' select='../Method[RoomId = current()/RoomId]' />
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select='concat(RoomName," (",RoomId,")")' />:
        method = <xsl:value-of select='concat($method/Name," (",$method/RoomId,")")' />
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't specified the version of XSLT you are working with or your expected output. I am going to assume you want XSLT 1.0, want to copy the document, but add the linked method name under the Room and drop the Methods.

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Method"/>

<xsl:template match="Room">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../Method[RoomId=current()/RoomId]/Name"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**... when applied to your sample input document, will produce ...**

```
<dsInventory>
  <Room>
    <RoomName>kantoor 1</RoomName>
    <RoomId>1376257</RoomId>
    <Name>test</Name>
  </Room>
  <Room>
    <RoomName>Hal</RoomName>
    <RoomId>1376258</RoomId>
    <Name>test</Name>
  </Room>
</dsInventory>
```

### Explanation

Use the current() function to specify the current item relative to the sequence constructor for the Room template, which in this case is a Room element. In the predicate we compare current()/RoomId with the RoomId of the Method step of our select expression. Thus linked Names are copied under Room. No xsl:if, no xsl:for-each, no variables. All can be achieved in the select expression using the current() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/dsInventory/Room">
    <xsl:for-each select="/dsInventory/Method">
        <xsl:if test="RoomId=../RoomId"></xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As the people, who answered this question pointed out, you are trying to compare a `/dsInventory/Method/RoomId` to a `/dsInventory/RoomId` and the latter doesn't exist in the provided XML document.

> I'm trying to select the methods for the corresponding rooms based on
>   the roomid.

**Here is a complete transformation, showing how to do this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Room">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="grab" 
         select="/*/Method[RoomId = current()/RoomId]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Method" mode="grab">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Method | Method/RoomId"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one with changed method names -- to be different from each other):

```
<dsInventory>
    <Room>
        <RoomName>kantoor 1</RoomName>
        <RoomId>1376257</RoomId>
    </Room>
    <Room>
        <RoomName>Hal</RoomName>
        <RoomId>1376258</RoomId>
    </Room>
    <Method>
        <RoomId>1376257</RoomId>
        <Name>test1</Name>
    </Method>
    <Method>
        <RoomId>1376258</RoomId>
        <Name>test2</Name>
    </Method>
</dsInventory>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (methods added to rooms and the `Method` children of the top element deleted):

```
<dsInventory>
   <Room>
      <RoomName>kantoor 1</RoomName>
      <RoomId>1376257</RoomId>
      <Method>
         <Name>test1</Name>
      </Method>
   </Room>
   <Room>
      <RoomName>Hal</RoomName>
      <RoomId>1376258</RoomId>
      <Method>
         <Name>test2</Name>
      </Method>
   </Room>
</dsInventory>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
2. A template, overriding the identity template, matches `Room`. Here the `Room` element is "shallow-copied and templates are applied to its children (which selects the identity template for them and they are copied "as-is" to the output) and then templates are applied to any `Method`, whose `RoomId` child has the same value as the `RoomId` child of the currently matched (**[`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-current)**) `Room` element. Because we also want to later delete any `Method` element, here we specify that the wanted processing (different from deletion) is to be done in `"grab"` mode.
3. A second template overriding the identity template deletes all `Method` elements by simply matching them and having an empty body.
4. The template that matches a `Method` in mode `"grab"` simply shallow-copies it and applies templates to its children. Of its children the `Name` is matched only by the identity template and is copied "as-is". The `RoomId` child is matched by a more specific template than the identity template and the former is chosen for execution. The chosen template has no body, which effectively "deletes" the matched `Method/RoomId` from the output.